# Upgrade from 2.7.2 to 2.10.3 - stuck login

Tags: login, upgrade

I just went through the upgrade process from 2.7.2 to 2.10.3. Now when I try to login, the login page just refreshes. I've tried different browsers and restarting browsers. No error messages, just a page refresh. Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Normally it's a case of clearing browser cookies, but have you tried manually deleting the EE cache files in system/expression engine/cache?

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with the browser cookie bug. This seems to be related to something else. Haven't tried manually deleting cache files, I'll try that. I rolled back the update, tried it again, and got a white screen. Then I rolled it back again (to 2.7.2), updated all add-ons, and get the same page refresh behavior. I can finally login if I set $config['allow_extensions'] = 'n'. Must be something related to an add-on. I'll keep troubleshooting.

Comment: Just a thought but does this site use MSM by any chance?? I've seen this behaviour before with an older 2.x site, where the admin session for SITE2 causes the login to refresh on SITE1. If you use MSM check you deleted the cookies from all the site domains.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cookies and my MSM query above fails you, perhaps review some of the comments on this bug report : https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19334

It's for older versions but there's a few nuggets that will help you. For instance some people report login issues using Zoo Flexible Admin or Republic Analytics which are both extensions.

Also (from the link), might be worth searching your third_party directory or your exp_extensions table for extensions using the `cp_member_login` hook, will help you identify the culprit as you commented that disabling extensions fixed things up nicely...

Also, check our session domain and/or perhaps try juggling the Admin CP session type and check your `$config['cp_url']` value.

Though, as you state it's probably down to an extension using the CP hook that is incompatible or something, just need to locate the offender. Let us know how you fare!

Comment: There are some interesting tidbits in that thread and your answer above. I appreciate the leads. I suspect it may be something with Structure. If I can devote more time to troubleshoot it, I'll try to confirm that and get back to you.